# Chromiumos Autotest

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, chromium-os

When i am running already present autotest suites from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/autotest/+/master/client/site_tests

I am observing that every time it logs out and logs in using test@test.test is it possible to remove this login and logout mechanism altogether. If yes then how.

output of one run coped below

---

localhost ~ # /usr/local/autotest/bin/autotest /usr/local/autotest/site_tests/DECREASE_VOLUME/control
15:40:28 INFO | Writing results to /usr/local/autotest/results/default
15:40:28 INFO | START   ----    ----    timestamp=1516615828    localtime=Jan 22 15:40:28
15:40:28 INFO | File /var/lib/cleanup_logs_paused was already present
15:40:28 INFO |         START   DECREASE_VOLUME DECREASE_VOLUME timestamp=1516615828    localtime=Jan 22 15:40:28
15:40:28 WARNI| Unable to import cv2 due to: Incorrect cv2 version found, expected 2.4.8 <= version < 3.0.0, found version $Rev: 4557 $
15:40:28 INFO | Starting before_hook for DECREASE_VOLUME
15:40:28 INFO | before_hook completed
15:40:28 INFO | Emulating keyboard Emulated Keyboard (/usr/local/autotest/cros/input_playback/keyboard.prop).
15:40:28 INFO | Found keyboard: Emulated Keyboard at /dev/input/event18.
15:40:28 INFO | Found other_keyboard: HP WMI hotkeys at /dev/input/event17.
15:40:28 INFO | Found mouse: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad at /dev/input/event7.
15:40:28 INFO | Found mouse: PS/2 Generic Mouse at /dev/input/event6.
15:40:28 INFO | Found keyboard: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard at /dev/input/event5.
15:40:28 INFO | Found other_keyboard: Video Bus at /dev/input/event4.
15:40:28 INFO | Found other_keyboard: Video Bus at /dev/input/event3.
15:40:28 INFO | Found other_keyboard: Power Button at /dev/input/event2.
15:40:28 INFO | Found other_keyboard: Sleep Button at /dev/input/event0.
15:40:28 INFO | ChromeOS BOARD = amd64-generic_2.9GHz_8GB
15:40:28 INFO | BattOr power monitor is not connected.
15:40:28 INFO | BattOr power monitor is not connected.
15:40:28 INFO | Chose browser: PossibleCrOSBrowser(browser_type=system)
15:40:28 INFO | (Re)starting the ui (logs the user out)
15:40:29 INFO | Restarting Chrome (pid=31701) with remote port
15:40:29 INFO | dbus-send --system --type=method_call --dest=org.chromium.SessionManager /org/chromium/SessionManager org.chromium.SessionManagerInterface.EnableChromeTesting boolean:true array:string:"--enable-net-benchmarking,--metrics-recording-only,--no-default-browser-check,--no-first-run,--enable-gpu-benchmarking,--deny-permission-prompts,--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required,--disable-search-geolocation-disclosure,--enable-smooth-scrolling,--enable-threaded-compositing,--remote-debugging-port=0,--start-maximized,--ash-disable-system-sounds,--allow-failed-policy-fetch-for-test,--oobe-skip-postlogin,--disable-logging-redirect,--vmodule=*/chromeos/net/*=2\,*/chromeos/login/*=2\,chrome_browser_main_posix=2,--disable-gaia-services"
15:40:30 INFO | DoNothingForwarder started between 127.0.0.1:40371 and 40371
15:40:30 INFO | Got devtools config: ws://127.0.0.1:40371/devtools/browser/81a7aea0-779d-473c-b8dd-ceb02a96ff49
15:40:30 INFO | Invoking Oobe.loginForTesting
15:40:31 INFO | Got devtools config: ws://127.0.0.1:40371/devtools/browser/81a7aea0-779d-473c-b8dd-ceb02a96ff49
15:40:34 INFO | Browser is up!
15:40:34 INFO | Browser started (pid=31752).
15:40:34 INFO | OS: chromeos
15:40:35 INFO | Browser command line: /opt/google/chrome/chrome --ui-prioritize-in-gpu-process --use-gl=egl --gpu-sandbox-failures-fatal=no --enable-logging --log-level=1 --use-cras --enable-wayland-server --user-data-dir=/home/chronos --max-unused-resource-memory-usage-percentage=5 --system-developer-mode --login-profile=user --aura-legacy-power-button --enterprise-enrollment-initial-modulus=15 --enterprise-enrollment-modulus-limit=19 --login-manager --enable-net-benchmarking --metrics-recording-only --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --enable-gpu-benchmarking --deny-permission-prompts --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --disable-search-geolocation-disclosure --enable-smooth-scrolling --enable-threaded-compositing --remote-debugging-port=0 --start-maximized --ash-disable-system-sounds --allow-failed-policy-fetch-for-test --oobe-skip-postlogin --disable-logging-redirect --disable-gaia-services --testing-channel=NamedTestingInterface:/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.C3jnsJ/.org.chromium.Chromium.Bnp8CH --vmodule=automatic_reboot_manager=1,tablet_power_button_controller=1,*chromeos/login/*=1,auto_enrollment_controller=1,*plugin*=2,*zygote*=1,*/ui/ozone/*=1,*/ui/display/manager/chromeos/*=1,*night_light*=1,power_button_observer=2,webui_login_view=2,lock_state_controller=2,webui_screen_locker=2,screen_locker=2,*/chromeos/net/*=2,*/chromeos/login/*=2,chrome_browser_main_posix=2
15:40:35 INFO | GPU device 0: VENDOR = 0x1002 (ATI), DEVICE = 0x6601
15:40:35 INFO | GPU device 1: VENDOR = 0x8086 (Intel), DEVICE = 0xa16
15:40:35 INFO | GPU Attributes:
15:40:35 INFO |   amd_switchable      : True
15:40:35 INFO |   basic_info_state    : 1
15:40:35 INFO |   can_support_threaded_texture_mailbox: False
15:40:35 INFO |   context_info_state  : 1
15:40:35 INFO |   direct_composition  : False
15:40:35 INFO |   direct_rendering    : True
15:40:35 INFO |   driver_date         :
15:40:35 INFO |   driver_vendor       : Mesa
15:40:35 INFO |   driver_version      : 17.3.0
15:40:35 INFO |   encrypted_only      : False
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_extensions       : GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_viewport_array GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_depth_stencil GL_NV_read_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_INTEL_performance_query GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_NV_image_formats GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_OES_tessellation_point_size GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_EXT_blend_func_extended GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT_geometry_point_size GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical GL_KHR_no_error GL_OES_geometry_point_size GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_renderer         : Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_reset_notification_strategy: 33362
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_vendor           : Intel Open Source Technology Center
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_version          : OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.3.0-devel (git-11adea4b24)
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_ws_extensions    : EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers EGL_KHR_config_attribs EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_no_config_context EGL_KHR_reusable_sync EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_MESA_configless_context EGL_MESA_drm_image EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_ws_vendor        : Mesa Project
15:40:35 INFO |   gl_ws_version       : 1.4 (DRI2)
15:40:35 INFO |   in_process_gpu      : False
15:40:35 INFO |   initialization_time : 0.020351
15:40:35 INFO |   jpeg_decode_accelerator_supported: True
15:40:35 INFO |   max_framerate_denominator: 1
15:40:35 INFO |   max_framerate_numerator: 30
15:40:35 INFO |   max_msaa_samples    : 8
15:40:35 INFO |   max_resolution_height: 4096
15:40:35 INFO |   max_resolution_width: 4096
15:40:35 INFO |   min_resolution_height: 16
15:40:35 INFO |   min_resolution_width: 16
15:40:35 INFO |   optimus             : False
15:40:35 INFO |   passthrough_cmd_decoder: False
15:40:35 INFO |   pixel_shader_version: 3.10
15:40:35 INFO |   process_crash_count : 0
15:40:35 INFO |   profile             : 3
15:40:35 INFO |   sandboxed           : True
15:40:35 INFO |   software_rendering  : False
15:40:35 INFO |   supports_overlays   : False
15:40:35 INFO |   vertex_shader_version: 3.10
15:40:35 INFO |   video_decode_accelerator_flags: 0
15:40:35 INFO | Feature Status:
15:40:35 INFO |   2d_canvas           : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   checker_imaging     : enabled_on
15:40:35 INFO |   flash_3d            : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   flash_stage3d       : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   flash_stage3d_baseline: enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   gpu_compositing     : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   multiple_raster_threads: enabled_on
15:40:35 INFO |   native_gpu_memory_buffers: disabled_software
15:40:35 INFO |   rasterization       : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   video_decode        : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   webgl               : enabled
15:40:35 INFO |   webgl2              : enabled
15:40:35 INFO | Driver Bug Workarounds:
15:40:35 INFO |   clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
15:40:35 INFO |   count_all_in_varyings_packing
15:40:35 INFO |   decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
15:40:35 INFO |   disable_discard_framebuffer
15:40:35 INFO |   msaa_is_slow
15:40:35 INFO |   rely_on_implicit_sync_for_swap_buffers
15:40:35 INFO |   scalarize_vec_and_mat_constructor_args
15:40:35 INFO | Playing back finger-movement on /dev/input/event18, file=/usr/local/autotest/cros/input_playback/keyboard_f9.
15:40:35 INFO | Blocking for 0.468029022217 seconds after playback.
15:40:35 INFO | Closing browser (pid=31752) ...
15:40:35 INFO | (Re)starting the ui (logs the user out)
15:40:36 INFO | Browser is closed.
15:40:36 INFO | Starting after_hook for DECREASE_VOLUME
15:40:36 INFO | HWID not available; not logging it as a test keyval.
15:40:37 INFO | after_hook completed
15:40:37 INFO |                 GOOD    DECREASE_VOLUME DECREASE_VOLUME timestamp=1516615837    localtime=Jan 22 15:40:37       completed successfully
15:40:37 INFO |         END GOOD        DECREASE_VOLUME DECREASE_VOLUME timestamp=1516615837    localtime=Jan 22 15:40:37
15:40:37 INFO | Leaving existing /var/lib/cleanup_logs_paused file
15:40:37 INFO | END GOOD        ----    ----    timestamp=1516615837    localtime=Jan 22 15:40:37

---